# Make a TextBox behave like VS's Output Window?

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

When the debug updates are pouring into the Output window, you can either leave the carat where it is, and the scroll (ie your view) will remain at the bottom of the text as the updates continue to come in.. or at any time you can click somewhere in the text, and the updates now continue on below your current position. You're free to move around the text.

I have replaced all my Debug.WriteLine() calls with a custom writeToStatus() Sub which adds the line to an OrderedDictionary. Separately, a timer regularly iterates through the dictionary, adding entries to a StringBuilder, followed by myTextbox.Text = myStringBuilder.ToString()

If I try something like:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
  TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
  TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

...I stay at the bottom, but can't scroll up to see what's going on. The updates snap you right back down (as expected I guess, but not as intended).

Thus my question: Is there a way to mimic the functionality of the Output Window? So I can alternatively stay at the bottom of the textbox as it updates, or freely scroll around?

Comment: You could check if the caret is already at the end before adding text, and if yes, scroll to the caret after you added the text, if not, don't do the scrolling. Or you could stop scrolling in case your textbox is focused. Also, if you wish to redirect your debug messages, you could also add a custom `TraceListener` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950732/redirect-debug-writeline-stream-to-a-textblock